# How to find a Integer variable by its value using a debugger?

Tags: javascript

is there a way to find all variables with a specific value in JS?

I know there is a variable holding value integer 374646 but I can not find it in sources (large codebase).

I think one can implement a solution by recursively checking all variables returned by `this` but I am not a JS developer

update:
the original question was confusing I think.

is there any way that I can find variables by values in a browser debugger (Chrome/Firefox)?

Comment: this is for debugging

Comment: What's the budget allocated? /s

Comment: "I think one can implement a solution by recursively checking all variables returned by this" — You can't. `this` doesn't return variables.

Comment: I mean in the debugger console of browsers

Comment: maybe you can find the answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276206/list-all-js-global-variables-used-by-site-not-all-defined, my question wasn't answered, but still lots of answers are about YOUR problem

Comment: Your edit asking *"is there any way that I can find variables by values in a browser debugger (Chrome/Firefox)?"* is completely different from your original question, which was clearly about using **code** to do it (*"I think one can implement a solution by recursively checking all variables returned by `this`"*).

Comment: yes I agree, I should mention debugger in the title. thank you for comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think one can implement a solution by recursively checking all variables returned by this but I am not a JS developer

No, you can't. Properties are not variables (except in one special case: a certain class of global variables are properties of the global object).

Unless your variable is a global, and it's the kind of global that's available as a property on the global object, you can't find it. There is no way to get a list of other kinds of variables.

For example, there is no way for code at global scope to find `a` in the following:

```js
const handle = (() => {
    const a = 374646;
    return setInterval(() => {
        console.log(a);
    }, 500);
})();
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(handle), 4000);
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Please note that it's dangerous and do not access the sites, that you don't know with that approach!!! All your data may get stolen, your girlfriend may get r@$%ped, your grandma may die, your dog may bite you in the crotch, all the glaciers in the world may melt, you can get herpes or even start a global nuclear war! Use at own risk! A very high risk if you don't know what running a browser without cross-domain policies means!**

Run your browser with cross-domain policies disabled (for example `Chromium` / `Chrome` with `--disable-web-security` param, note : Kill all chrome instances before running command or it won't work), then in the console `copy-paste` this function:

```
function globalSearch(startObject, value) {
    var stack = [[startObject,'']];
    var searched = [];
    var found = false;

    var isArray = function(test) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call( test ) === '[object Array]';
    }

    while(stack.length) {
        var fromStack = stack.pop();
        var obj = fromStack[0];
        var address = fromStack[1];

        if( typeof obj == typeof value && obj == value) {
            var found = address;
            break;
        }else if(typeof obj == "object" && searched.indexOf(obj) == -1){
           if ( isArray(obj) ) {
              var prefix = '[';
              var postfix = ']';
           }else {
              var prefix = '.';
              var postfix = '';
           }
           for( i in obj ) {
              stack.push( [ obj[i], address + prefix + i + postfix ] );
           }
           searched.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return found == '' ? true : found;
}
```

After that you can search variable by values with:

```
globalSearch(window,value);
```

> **Once again! Remember that it's dangerous and do not access the sites, that you don't know with that approach!!! Disclaimer: If something will happen, you didn't even see that post, I didn't write it! I don't know what `StackOverflow` is! Never been here.**